Rationalize the denominator $\frac{2\sqrt{a+1}}{\sqrt{a-1}-\sqrt{2a}+\sqrt{a+1}}$
I attempted to solve this by letting $c=\sqrt{a-1}$ and $b=\sqrt{a+1}$ squaring both and adding yields $b^2+c^2=2a$ plugging everything in gets $ 2b/(c-\sqrt{ b^2+c^2 }+b)$
once I rationalize everything I am left with the equation $ 1+b/c+\sqrt{c^2+b^2}/c $ plugging everything back in $ 1+\sqrt{(a-1)/(a+1)}+\sqrt{(2a)/(a+1)}$ the answer at the back of the book is $ (a-1+\sqrt{a^2-1}+\sqrt{2a(a-1))}/(a-1)$ when I graph my answer and the back of the book answer the positive x axis is the same but the negative one is mirrored for some reason
the blue one is the answer I got  my intuition says the reason this is like this is that the square root function is not defined on the negative axis and by substituting I'm messing with this idk, id like to know why?

If $c=\sqrt{a-1};b=\sqrt{a+1}$ just do $((c+b)-\sqrt{2a})((c+b)+\sqrt{2a})$ to get $(c+b)^2 -2a= c^2 + 2cb + b^2 -2a= (a-1) +\sqrt{(a-1)(a+1)} + (a+1) - 2a= \sqrt{(a-1)(a+1)}= \sqrt{a^2-1}$.  Then just multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{a^2-1}$.

In other words... $\frac {k}{\sqrt{a-1}+\sqrt{a+1} - \sqrt {2a}}=\frac {k(\sqrt{a-1}+\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{2a})}{(\sqrt{a-1}+\sqrt{a+1} - \sqrt {2a})((\sqrt{a-1}+\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{2a})}=\frac M{(\sqrt{a-1} + \sqrt{a+1})^2 - 2a}=\frac M{(a-1 + a+1 + 2\sqrt{(a-1)(a+1)}-2a}=\frac M{2\sqrt{a^2-1}}= \frac {M\sqrt{a^2-1}}{2\sqrt{a^2-1}\sqrt{a^2-1}}=\frac J{2(a^2-1)}$. Denominator realtionalized.

@fleablood Even that's a slight overkill in this particular instance: $k=\sqrt{a+1}$, so the factor of $\sqrt{a+1}$ in the denominator cancels immediately and only $\sqrt{a-1}$ remains.

Yeah.... but the question was how to rationalize the denominator so I concentrated that that can always be done.  Of course reducing the fraction is another issue as one always can overrationalize* a denominator.  (I wrote an answer using my technique and wanted to show how "brainlessly" choosing a garbage-in why of ratializing each term arbtrarily right to left [so the "$+\sqrt{a+1}$" first].  It did work but a a ridiculously overly large fraction will huge common factors, that I felt every point I was making was refuted by practicality.  So I never posted it.)

Ideas for solving
Simplify expression with new variables and apply "conjuguate multiplication" selecting one square-root term you want to make disappear, do it again, each time you have one less terms in the denominator that is a square root term.
Solution :
Noting :
$$x=\sqrt{a-1} $$
$$y=\sqrt{a} $$
$$z=\sqrt{a+1} $$
and
$$y^2-x^2=1$$
$$z^2-y^2=1$$
$$ z^2-x^2= 2$$
$$yz=\sqrt{a^2+a}$$
$$yx=\sqrt{a^2-1}$$
The quotient is :
$$Q=\dfrac{2z}{x-2y+z}$$
$$Q= \dfrac{2z(x+2y-z)}{(x-2y+z)(x+2y-z)} =\dfrac{2z(x+2y-z)}{(x^2+2xy-zx-2xy-4y^2+2yz+zx+2xy-z^2)} $$
$$Q= \dfrac{2z(x+2y-z))}{(x-2y+z)(x+2y-z)} =\dfrac{2z(x+2y-z))}{(x^2-4y^2+2y(z+x)-z^2)} $$
Can you end from here and eliminate the last square root $2y(z+x)$ at the denominator apply same idea
?

Based on the notation you've chosen, you should actually have $Q=2z/(x-\sqrt{2}y+z)$ to match the problem statement. I suggest defining $y=\sqrt{2a}$ instead, so that $Q=2z/(x-y+z)$. I also think it's better in the present scenario to rationalize using the factor $x+y+z$: the difference of squares $(x+z)^2-(2y)^2$ simplifies rather nicely.

Yes i've been a bit fast thanks !
